# Error at trying to write batch item in dynamodb with Mapvalues

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I've successfully use write batch items with boto library. However when I've tried to add map values to the request I've got the following exception:

Invalid type for parameter RequestItems.TestMap, value:

```
{'PutRequest': 
    {'Item': {
     'field1': {'S': '0.0'}, 
     'field2': {'M': {'Age': {'N': '35'}, 'Name': {'S': 'Joe'}}}
      }
     }
}
, type: <type 'dict'>, valid types: <type 'list'>, <type 'tuple'>*
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Regards,
Iván.

Comment: I am just wondering whether the answer was helpful?

Comment: Sorry notionquest for not answering back before. I made it work using "M" in the json file. The problem was not related to the structure itself of the field2 but the way I was passing as a parameter

Answer (score 0):

The **`field2`** can be formed like this. The DynamoDB will automatically interpret it as MAP (i.e. no need to specifically mention 'M'). If you specifically mention, it would create nested map structure (refer screen shot two).

```
'field2': {'Age': 35, 'Name': 'Joe'}
```

Your code would create nested maps.

```
response = table.put_item(
   Item={
        'yearkey': year,
        'title': title,
        'info': {
            'plot':"Nothing happens at all.",
            'rating': decimal.Decimal(0)
        },
        'field2': {'Age': 35, 'Name': 'Joe'}
    }
)
```

**Map Structure (Correct):-**

[image: Map in DynamoDB]

**Nested Map Structure (Incorrect):-**

[image: Nested Map Structure]

Answer (score 0):

The error I got was not referring to the format itself but the type. Once I encapsuled the object within an array everything went ok